# Пересылка фото в другой чат (Телеграм). aiogram

Tags: python, aiogram

Нужно переслать фотографию в другой чат, которую присылают боту.

Когда делаю с текстом - все срабатывает и пересылается

```
@dp.message_handler(content_types=["text"])  
async def replying(msg):  
      await bot.send_message(XXXXXXX, msg.text)
```

Но когда я меняю на:

```
@dp.message_handler(content_types=["photo"])
async def replying(pic):
      await bot.send_photo(XXXXXXXX, pic.photo)
```

То, ничего не срабатывает. Что бы переслать фото, его нужно обязательно сохранить на комп?

Если можно без этого, то как?

А если уж с сохранением, то напишите хоть так...

Comment: Свой вариант ответа лучше добавить отдельным ответом, а не изменять вопрос.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В параметре `photo` лежит не фотография, а список из фотографии разных размеров.

Для того, что переслать фотографию из сообщения, забирайте последний элемент из списка, и отправляйте по file_id полученной фотографии:

```py
await bot.send_photo(XXXXXXXX, pic.photo[-1].file_id)
```

Вот описание Message из документации: https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#message